# How to get the next date / how to get length of each stay

Tags: mysql

I need to calculate how many people subscribe in a month e.g. January, and when they leave: it looks like:so it would look like:

e.g. looking at January where there are 50 subscribers

```
MONTH(t2.leavedate) || COUNT(t1.subscribed1) 
January             || 10
February            || 15
March               || 3
```

So there are 50 people in the January cohort (i.e. 50 people subscribed in January) and 28 people left- I want my query to output when the 28 people left.

This is the table (tableX) which I have that shows each event and the user_id:

I have this table that has the events

```
id||user_id||event_name||date of event
4 ||   10  || subscribe|| 2016-01-25
5 ||   11  || subscribe|| 2016-01-30
6 ||   12  || subscribe|| 2016-01-30
7 ||   13  || leave    || 2016-02-02
8 ||   14  || subscribe|| 2016-02-03
```

If I filter out to just one user, user_id = 10(user10) - where user10 is an example of a rejoiner (multiple 'subscribe' events, and multiple 'leave', the table would like:

```
id ||user_id||event_name||date of event
 4 ||   10  || subscribe|| 2016-01-25
20 ||   10  || leave    || 2016-01-30
32 ||   10  || subscribe|| 2016-01-30
45 ||   10  || leave    || 2016-02-02
60 ||   10  || subscribe|| 2016-02-03
70 ||   10  || leave    || 2016-03-10
```

This is the query I have to count the number of subscribers in a month:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(t1.joindate), COUNT(t1.subscribed1)
FROM tableX
JOIN
(SELECT tableX.user_id AS subscribed1, tableX.date_of_event AS joindate
    FROM 
        tableX
    WHERE tableX.event_name = "subscribed"
    GROUP BY tableX.id
    )t1
    ON t1.subscribed1 = tableX.user_id
WHERE event_name = 'subscribed'
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(t1.joindate)
ORDER BY t1.joindate ASC;
```

The problem I am having is that, if I am looking at e.g. January- rejoiners, e.g. user10, will come up as 2 (COUNT(tableX.ids)) when counting the number of subscribers- but will come up 3 times when I COUNT(t1.subscribed1) as leaving twice in January, and once in March (altogether, it will show that user10, as part of the January cohort, leaves three times, and again, user10 will show up in my subscriber count in February cohort- but show that the user left 3 times. When what I want for the February cohort, would be user10 to be counted as once in February, and left once in March)

I want to count these events in order e.g. the next leave date for February-- is March. I've tried using functions such as MAX-MIN and t2.leavedate >= t1.joindate

This is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't seem to reflect the right numbers:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(t2.leavedate), COUNT(t2.cancelled2)

    FROM tableX

JOIN 

(SELECT MONTHNAME(tableX.date_of_event), tableX.user_id AS subscribed1, tableX.date_of_event AS joindate
    FROM 
        user_account_events
    WHERE tableX.event_name = "subscribed"

    GROUP BY tableX.id
    )t1

    ON t1.subscribed1 = tableX.user_id

JOIN 

    (SELECT tableX.user_id AS cancelled2, tableX.date_of_event AS leavedate
        FROM tableX
    WHERE
        tableX.event_name = "leave"
    GROUP BY tableX.user_id
    )t2
    ON t2.cancelled2 = t1.subscribed1


WHERE tableX.date_of_event = 'leave'
AND t1.joindate BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-01 00:00:00'
*AND t2.leavedate >= t1.joindate*

GROUP BY MONTH(t2.leavedate)
ORDER BY t2.leavedate;
```

Expected output for January cohort i.e: (t1.joindate BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-01 00:00:00')

```
MONTH(t2.leavedate) || COUNT(t1.subscribed1) 
January             || 10
February            || 15
```

So, eventually, I want to create a table that looks like this:

```
                    Nov || Dec || Jan || Feb ||
No. of Subscribers|| 10 || 15  || 50  || 25  ||

Leave Month
              Nov || 1  ||     ||
              Dec || 3  || 2   ||
              Jan || 1  || 5   || 10 || 
              Feb || 2  || 3   || 15 || 6 ||
               ____________________________
 Total 'leaves'   || 7 || 10  || 25  || 6 ||
```

i.e. 7 people out of the 10 people that subscribed in November have left. (only 3 active subscribers from the November cohort)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show your expected output. And why there are two sets of input?

Comment: @1000111 Apologies, am trying to lay out the question as well as I can, I forgot to add that the second output is what a rejoiner would look like, and how rejoiner users can distort by data since their 'leave' date would be counted more than once. for example, for user_id = 10 (user10) will come up in the January cohort twice, which is fine, but the trouble is when I ask when they leave, because then, it will show that the user left in January (twice) and March. So, I want it to only show that user10 left in relation to the first two joindate in January.

Comment: I think you can do better.

Comment: can you show us your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This query let you know if a "user_id" is suscribed or not at some date

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(IF(event_name="suscribe", 1, -1)) AS is_suscribed FROM `tableX` WHERE date_of_event < '2016-01-25' GROUP BY user_id
```

If you want suscribers count in a month:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(IF(event_name="suscribe", 1, -1)) AS is_suscribed FROM `tableX` WHERE MONTH(date_of_event)=1 AND YEAR(date_of_event)=2016 GROUP BY user_id) AS real_suscription WHERE is_suscribed > 0
```

Or if you want unsuscribers count in a month:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(IF(event_name="suscribe", 1, -1)) AS is_suscribed FROM `tableX` WHERE MONTH(date_of_event)=1 AND YEAR(date_of_event)=2016 GROUP BY user_id) AS real_suscription WHERE is_suscribed < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this might be good for you

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(next_leave_date, '%Y-%m'), 
  count(user_id) 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    tableX.user_id AS user_id, 
    MAX(tableX.date_of_event) AS next_leave_date
  FROM 
    tableX 
    JOIN ( -- get target user lists
      SELECT 
        DISTINCT user_id
      FROM 
        tableX
      WHERE date_of_event >= '2015-01-01'
        and date_of_event <  '2015-02-01'
    ) AS target_users ON tableX.user_id = target_users.user_id
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT 
        user_id, min(date_of_event)
      FROM
        tableX
      WHERE date_of_event >= '2015-02-01'
        AND event_name = 'subscribed'
        AND user_id IN (
          SELECT 
            DISTINCT user_id
          FROM 
            tableX
          WHERE date_of_event >= '2015-01-01'
            and date_of_event <  '2015-02-01'
        )
      GROUP BY user_id
    ) AS taget_users_with_next_sub_date ON tableX.user_id = taget_users_with_next_sub_date.user_id
  WHERE event_name = 'leave'
  GROUP BY tableX.user_id
) AS users_and_their_date_of_leave
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(next_leave_date, '%Y-%m');
```

this is a relatively complicated SQL query. what i put here can only help you to analyze users who subscribed in a month. so if you want to do coherent analysis you need to run it multiple times, each time with a different month.

i would recommend you to do it in a store procedure and put the month as the parameter, this could save you some time.